# cypress cant find element after page reload

Tags: cypress

Have the below cypress test.  its failing  element can't be found.  increased the command timeout to 10 seconds. but still its saying  "Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find element: #Contact name, but never found it."  But I can see in the cypress UI page is loaded and id is correct.  Tried intercept, pagereload & other things but still not working.  Its a vue js nuxt application talking to php backend

```
it.only('test', ()=>{
  cy.visit('https://rms.test/sales/');
   cy.wait(60000) 
   cy.get('#Contact\ name').type(username)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` character is being parsed out of the selector (you can see there is no `\` in the Cypress log).

You can get the right element by using attribute startsWith `^=` and endsWith `$=` selectors like this

```js
cy.get('[id^="Contact"][id$="name"]').type('Lola')
cy.get('[id^="Contact"][id$="name"]').should('have.value', 'Lola')
```